# Compile a statically linked Solana binary

Tags: rust, cli

How does one compile Solana statically linking C libraries?  If I run ldd on a Solana binary, I get:

```
$ ldd $(which solana)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd70517000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f73fdf04000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f73fdede000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f73fdec4000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f73fdeba000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f73fde99000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f73fdd16000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f73fdb54000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f73ff27d000)
```

I am using the following command to compile Solana, but the libudev link does not work:

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl 
RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

The error is:

```
   Compiling hidapi v1.4.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `hidapi v1.4.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/solana/solana/target/release/build/hidapi-65499cb656bc1d2f/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libudev: `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "libudev"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  --- stderr
  Package libudev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libudev.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libudev' found
  ', /home/solana/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hidapi-1.4.1/build.rs:57:54
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're missing the [system build dependencies](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/README.md#1-install-rustc-cargo-and-rustfmt)

At present they are as follow for linux

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libudev-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev llvm clang cmake make libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```

Note that musl isn't a supported build target, so you may have a bit of a project on your hands

Comment: Thanks for the post.   I installed these dependencies, but my binaries were not portable across VMs.  

Regarding musl, I had particular trouble getting libudev to compile.  Is there a way to turn off some feature to get rid of the libudev dependency?

Also, is there a chance that the solana crate on crates.io will be updated as [this link](https://salsa.debian.org/rust-team/debcargo-conf/blob/master/README.rst#packaging-a-crate-for-debian) provides an avenue to create a debian package that handles C libraries.  I like to GPG verify my binaries, hence the motivation for the post.

Comment: please make new posts for new questions